# Embedded google drive api to show a pdf returns 204

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

My website has an iframe pointing to https://drive.google.com/viewer?url=https://mywebsite/myfile.pdf&embedded=true

Most of the times, the pdf loads correctly, but sometimes it doesn't, I get just a blank page. The request seems to be returning 204 (request successful - response empty).

I could even replicate this, by entering the url above directly on the browser, and refreshing multiple times, until I got a 204, so it is not something on my website and/or the iframe.. any idea why this happens? and how to prevent it.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score -1):

The error HTTP Status 204 (No Content) indicates that the server has successfully fulfilled the request and that there is no content to send in the response payload body. The server might want to return updated meta information in the form of entity-headers, which if present SHOULD be applied to current document’s active view if any.

> By default, 204 (No Content) response is cacheable. If caching needs
>   to be overridden then response must include cache respective [cache
>   headers](https://restfulapi.net/caching/).

In order to solve this issue, **the lost update problem**, the server may also include HTTP header `ETag` to let the client validate client side resource representation before making further update on server:

> Lost update problem happens when multiple people edit a resource
>   without knowledge of each other’s changes. In this scenario, the last
>   person to update a resource “wins”, and previous updates are lost.
>   ETags can be used in combination with the `If-Match` header to let the
>   server decide if a resource should be updated. If `ETag` does not match
>   then server informs the client via a `412 (Precondition Failed)`
>   response.

Please check this [site](https://restfulapi.net/http-status-204-no-content/) for more details.

Comment: But how does it help to solve the problem? Which, in this case, is specific one; Google Drive